# How to fix error get data from main form in user control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a small form and a user control , but I don't know how to pass data from one side of the database to the other user control , followed some tutorials on the net and I used the (get;set) pair like that. this:

**IN Main form**

```
string query = @"select t.Ma_Nvu,t.Ten_Nvu,t.Time_Start,t.Time_End,d.Noi_dung from ToDoList_ListNvu t
                left join ToDoList_NoiDungNvu d on t.Ma_Nvu = d.Ma_Nvu
                where t.Status like N'Chưa hoàn thành'";
        dt = (new Data()).executeQuery(query);
        if (dt.Rows.Count == 0) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Bạn cần tạo nhiệm vụ trước để vào !", "Thông báo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else
        {
            ProcessToDoList tdl = new ProcessToDoList();
            BunifuTransition trans = new BunifuTransition();
            this.PageToDoList.Controls.Add(tdl);
            tdl.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            tdl.Size = new Size(0, 567);
            if (tdl.Width == 0)
            {
                tdl.Width = 1014;
                trans.ShowSync(tdl, false, Bunifu.UI.WinForms.BunifuAnimatorNS.Animation.HorizBlind);
                tdl.BringToFront();
            }
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                DataList data = new DataList();
                data.Name = dr["Ten_Nvu"].ToString();
                data.Time_Start = dr["Time_Start"].ToString();
                data.Time_End = dr["Time_End"].ToString();
                data.Noi_Dung = dr["Noi_dung"].ToString();
                dtaAdd.Add(data);
            }
            int i = 0;
            while (i < dt.Rows.Count)
            {
                tdl.Name_Nvu = dtaAdd[i].Name;
                tdl.Noi_dung = dtaAdd[i].Noi_Dung;
                tdl.Time_Start = dtaAdd[i].Time_Start;
                tdl.Time_End = dtaAdd[i].Time_End;
                if (tdl.CheckOut()==true)
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }
```

**In UserControl**

```
public string Name_Nvu
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
    public string Noi_dung
    {
        get {return _noidung ; }
        set {_noidung = value; }
    }
    public string Time_Start
    {
        get { return _timestart; }
        set { _timestart = value; }
    }
    public string Time_End
    {
        get { return _timeend; }
        set { _timeend = value; }
    }
```

But it doesn't work. I don't know where the error is, so I want to ask everyone how can I pass data from form to user control.

Comment: What error is it?

Comment: To say it is an error is an exaggeration but when I run my program the values ​​on the usercontrol side are null and no value is received from the form side.

Comment: The last … `while (i < dt.Rows.Count) …` … looks odd in a sense that there is only ONE (1) `tdl` object and the `while` loop appears to be changing the properties of the "same" `tdl` object over and over… if this is intended, would it not be easier to simply grab the LAST row in the table … ? …

Comment: if `tdl.CheckOut()` ever returns false you'll get an infinite loop, unless it will eventually return true for the same set on inputs

Comment: Initially I was going to get the data on UserControl side but every time I call them, they will have to connect to the database, it makes my form very heavy. And I came up with an idea like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what error message ur getting, but passing value from your form to your UC could be done this way.

In your `User Control`:

```
  private string _name;
  [Category("Custom Props")]
  public string custom_name
  {
     get { return _name; }
     set { _name = value; }
  }
```

Then in your `form`, you can assign value to the `_name` string in the user control by doing something like this:

```
   myUC test = new myUC(); //Your user control
   test.custom_name = dtaAdd[i].Name; 
   panel1.Controls.Add(test);
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with my program when I run it it always returns null